# Describing an open interval I centered at c, $I \subseteq (a, b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Entire question:
**Let (a,b) be an open interval of Real numbers and let $c \in (a,b).$ Describe an open interval I centered at c such that $I \subseteq (a,b)$**

I didn't quite get where I should've headed, so I thought myself pretty clever when I devised this:

Take a real number i, such that $a < i < b$ and a real number j, such that $a < i < j < b$. Let the real number c: $i < c < j$.

Let I = (i, j). Now $I \subseteq (a,b)$

But the given solution was quite different: $ r = min(c - a, c - b)$ and $I = (c - r, c + r)$ now I is centered at c and $I \subseteq (a,b)$.

Now my question is, am I just dead-wrong here? What exactly is meant by centered? Exactly midway? I thought I sort of nailed it by defining some helper variables.

Comment: Centered means the midpoint of the subinterval should be $c$.

Comment: $r=\min(c-a,b-c)$ rather than $c-b$ which is always negative.

Comment: Actually the solution could allow a choice for $0<r\le\min(c-a,b-c)$. Now I notice there is actually a small mistake: it must be $b-c$, else $r$ will be negative and the resulting subinterval will be empty.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Beat me to it mate ;)

Comment: So basically, my definition of c isnt rigorous enough, in that 'my' c isnt necessarily the midpoint, but just some arbitrary point on my interval (i,j)

Comment: As I read the Question, $c$ was handed to you (specified) and you need to define a "balanced" open interval around it but contained in $(a,b)$.  The "solution" you got graded against is the largest such interval, but as AlexR points out, any smaller (positive) "radius" $r$ would work equally well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Asaf Karagila pointed out, $r=\min(c-a,b-c)$ would be correct. But I would advise to use
$$r = \min(|a-c|,|b-c|) \tag1$$
where (thanks to absolute values) we don't have to worry about the order of subtraction. The reason to prefer (1) is to prepare to divorce the idea of *distance* from *arithmetics* and *order*. The quantity $d(a,b)=|a-b|$ is all that we need to manipulate with, and its only relevant property is the triangle inequality.

The meaning of (1) is that the "radius" (half-length) allowed for the inner interval is given by the distance from $c$ to the boundary of the interval: 
$$r = \min_{x\in \partial I} |x-c| \tag2$$

The proof that every point $y$ with $|y-c|<r$ belongs to the interval can use the triangle inequality: 
$$c-|y-c| \le y\le c+|y-c|$$
hence 
$$a \le y\le b$$

---

Formula (2) generalizes to arbitrary *metric spaces*, in which we no longer talk about arithmetical operators.  Namely,
$$r = \inf_{x\in \partial A} d(x,c)\tag3$$
gives the radius of an open ball centered at $c$ and contained in $A$ (and the largest such). Of course, in general we might have $r=0$, but if $A$ is open, then $r>0$ for every $x\in A.